# Get text of next span after click a button

Tags: jquery

I want to use a button within a table to get the text of the **next** following span with the class 'tID' **in the same td-Element**.
Currently, I get no text. Thank you for your tip!

```js
$('.editTerm').on('click', function() {
  var currentID = $('tID span:first').text();
  alert('currentID: ', currentID);
});
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <button class="editTerm btn btn-default btn-xs" type="submit">
          <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
        </button> <span class="targetTerm">
  <span class="fM">Musculoskeletal syndrome</span></span>
        <span class="tID">Target ID: <strong>NVMDIS22475</strong></span> 
        <span class="prefTargetTerm">Preferred Term: <strong>syndrome</strong></span> 
        <span class="otherTargetInfo">Informations: <strong>Lorem Ipsum</strong></span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Use `siblings()`, `$(this).siblings('.tID span:first').text();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `this` keyword to reference the button which was clicked on. From there you can use `siblings()` to get the related `.tID` element, and `find()` to get the value in the `strong` tag. Try this:

```js
$('.editTerm').on('click', function() {
  var currentID = $(this).siblings('.tID').find('strong:first').text();
  alert('currentID: ' + currentID);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <button class="editTerm btn btn-default btn-xs" type="submit">
          <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
        </button> 
        <span class="targetTerm">
          <span class="fM">Musculoskeletal syndrome</span>
        </span>
        <span class="tID">Target ID: <strong>NVMDIS22475</strong></span> 
        <span class="prefTargetTerm">Preferred Term: <strong>syndrome</strong></span> 
        <span class="otherTargetInfo">Informations: <strong>Lorem Ipsum</strong></span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <button class="editTerm btn btn-default btn-xs" type="submit">
          <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
        </button> 
        <span class="targetTerm">
          <span class="fM">Foo bar syndrome</span>
        </span>
        <span class="tID">Target ID: <strong>F00B4r 1234</strong></span> 
        <span class="prefTargetTerm">Preferred Term: <strong>syndrome</strong></span> 
        <span class="otherTargetInfo">Informations: <strong>Dolor sit</strong></span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Note that this pattern has the advantage of working when there are multiple rows in your table, as the snippet demonstrates.

Answer (score 1):

Your selector is wrong. Except the `.` after `tID` you want to get `strong`:

```js
$('.editTerm').on('click', function() {
  var currentID = $(this)
    .parent() //get the parent td
    .find('span.tID strong') //get strong element that is child of span with tID class
    .text(); //get text
  console.log('currentID: ', currentID); //prints out: currentID:  NVMDIS22475
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <button class="editTerm btn btn-default btn-xs" type="submit">
          <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
        </button> <span class="targetTerm">
  <span class="fM">Musculoskeletal syndrome</span></span>
        <span class="tID">Target ID: <strong>NVMDIS22475</strong></span> 
        <span class="prefTargetTerm">Preferred Term: <strong>syndrome</strong></span> 
        <span class="otherTargetInfo">Informations: <strong>Lorem Ipsum</strong></span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Edit after your comment: You can use `this`(refer to DOM element).

Comment: @mm1975 Glad that I helped you.

Comment: I have still a problem: Within the table, there are a lot of classes tID. But It should take not the value of the first tID. It should take the value of the first tID in the same td

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.editTerm').on('click', function() {
  var currentID = $('span.tID:first').text();//use . for Class
  alert('currentID: ', currentID);
});
```